# What does this Flow JS "polymorphic type instead of intersection type" error mean?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, next.js

What does this Flow JS error mean?

`Expected polymorphic type instead of any member of intersection type.`

---

**Details:**

The error is thrown by `Document` in the export line below. I don't understand why it's happening or what I can do to fix it. (I tried looking this up in the Flow documentation, but still couldn't figure it out.)

```
// @flow
import Document, {Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document'

export default class IntlDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps (context) {
    const props = await super.getInitialProps(context)
    const {req: {localeDataScript}} = context
    return {
      ...props,
      localeDataScript
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: this.props.localeDataScript
            }}
          />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

And the `next/document` type declaration is this:

```
declare module "next/document" {
  import type {Component} from 'react';

  declare type Context = {
    pathname: string,
    query: any,
    req?: any,
    res?: any,
    xhr?: any,
    err?: any,
  };
  declare export var Head: Class<Component<void, *, *>>;
  declare export var Main: Class<Component<void, *, *>>;
  declare export var NextScript: Class<Component<void, *, *>>;
  declare export default Class<Component<void, *, *>> & {
    getInitialProps: (ctx: Context) => Promise<*>;
    renderPage(cb: Function): void;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I want to note that the code that you provided needs some updates to work with Flow v0.53.0 or later. That version made big changes to the way that Flow annotations for React work. In particular the `Component` class changed to taking two type parameters instead of three. I have made the necessary changes in the code snippets in my answer.

In the latest version of Flow (v0.59.0) the error message reports much more detail:

```
Error: react.js:7
  7: export default class IntlDocument extends Document {
                                               ^^^^^^^^ identifier `Document`. Expected polymorphic type instead of any member of intersection type
  7: export default class IntlDocument extends Document {
                                               ^^^^^^^^ intersection
  Member 1:
   15:   declare export default Class<Component<*, *>> & {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ class type: type application of Component. See lib: types/next-document.js:15
  Error:
    9:     const props = await super.getInitialProps(context)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `getInitialProps`. Property not found in
    9:     const props = await super.getInitialProps(context)
                               ^^^^^ statics of React$Component
  Member 2:
                                                         v
   15:   declare export default Class<Component<*, *>> & {
   16:     getInitialProps: (ctx: Context) => Promise<*>;
   17:     renderPage(cb: Function): void;
   18:   };
         ^ object type. See lib: types/next-document.js:15
  Error:
    7: export default class IntlDocument extends Document {
                                                 ^^^^^^^^ identifier `Document`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
                                                         v
   15:   declare export default Class<Component<*, *>> & {
   16:     getInitialProps: (ctx: Context) => Promise<*>;
   17:     renderPage(cb: Function): void;
   18:   };
         ^ object type. See lib: types/next-document.js:15


Found 1 error
```

The intersection type in question is the type `Document` (the default export of `"next/document"`), which is an intersection of

```
Class<Component<void, *, *>>
```

and

```
{
  getInitialProps: (ctx: Context) => Promise<*>;
  renderPage(cb: Function): void;
}
```

It looks like the intention is that `Document` is a subclass of React's `Component` class with the static methods `getInitialProps` and `renderPage`. Flow does see `getInitialProps` and `renderPage` as methods that can be called on `Document`. The problem is that Flow does not see those as static methods for purposes of subclassing; so your call to `super.getInitialProps(context)` fails.

A simple way around this is to change the invocation `super.getInitialProps(context)` to `Document.getInitialProps(context)`.

A better fix is to replace the type intersection with a proper class declaration in the `"next/document"` type definitions:

```
declare export default class Document<Props, State = void> extends React$Component<Props, State> {
  static getInitialProps(ctx: Context): Promise<Props>;
  static renderPage(cb: Function): void;
}
```

I can see why the original author did not do it this way. That type definition file imports the `Component` type like this:

```
import type {Component} from 'react';
```

In Flow a class is a value and a type with the same name. You need the value to create a subclass, because a subclass is something that exists at runtime, and types do not exist at runtime. That import brings in the `Component` type, but not the value, and Flow will not let you declare a subclass if the value is not in scope. If you try you will get an error like this:

```
types/next-document.js:26
 26:   declare export default class Document<Props, State = void> extends Component<Props, State> {
                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^ Component. type referenced from value position
  2:   import type {Component} from 'react';
                    ^^^^^^^^^ type Component
```

The original author imported the just the type because type definition files are not allowed to import values - they can only import types. The author found that they could not properly declare a subclass, and resorted to that type union workaround.

It happens that the type definitions for React (which are built into Flow, see [react.js](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js)) put some types into the global namespace. This is a workaround that type definition authors use sometimes due to problems importing things in type definition files. The convention is to prefix globally-scoped types with the capitalized module name and a dollar sign. So you can use the `React$Component` type in type definition files without importing it; which is what I did in the declaration above.